Actualizacion de dataset con API REST PBI
de casualidad alguno ha actualizado dataset mediante la api rest de PBI, hice este codigo que me arroja response 200 pero no me actualiza el dataset
def actualizarDataSet(idgrupo,idDataset,llave):
    endpoint = f'https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/groups/{idgrupo}/datasets/{idDataset}/refreshes?$top=1'
    print(endpoint)
    headers = {
        'Authorization' : f'Bearer ' + llave
    } 
    response_request = requests.get(endpoint, headers= headers)
    data = response_request.json()
    print(data)

si alguno me pudiera ayudar estaria garadecido

Aquí parece que solo estás solicitando GET lo que tiene el endpoint, algo como un SELECT. El proceso de actualización se debería hacer de otra manera, PUT o POST.

Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera medalla!
